# Matlab+mex compiled file using opencv cannot open a video (mpg) file

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, video

I need Matlab to deal with some mpg video data, with performance boosting using the OpenCV library. I used cvCaptureFromFile() to load the video. It works fine when compiled independently using g++ (Of course code should be modified from the following), however it failed to open the video file in Matlab when compiled with mex. The cvCaptureFromFile() always returns NULL when called within Matlab. There was no error message or warnings during compiling and linking with mex. Any ideas why ? Thank you in advance.

```
//OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit
//Matlab R2013a
//OpenCV: 2.4.9
//compiler: g++-4.4, or gcc-4.4


#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>

#include<cv.h>
#include<cvaux.h>
#include<highgui.h>

#include "mex.h"

using namespace std;

static CvCapture* capture = NULL;


void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

string filename;

filename = "test.mpg";

capture = cvCaptureFromFile(filename.c_str());

if (capture == NULL)
{
cout<<"Cannot open file!"<<endl;
}

}
```

Comment: are you sure you have the video file placed where the MEX-file can find it?

Comment: Yes. The test.mpg is placed in the same folder with compiled mex, and that's where Matlab call the mex file.

Comment: not related, but *if* you use opencv, use it's c++ api, not the deprecated c one.

Comment: It's actually part of an old code from others' lab. I wanna test its compatibility. Even using the old C api, in principle it should still work, or not ?